# How to store and retrieve DataGridViewRow in HidenField

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hidden-field, web-user-controls

I am building an `WebUserControl`, i need to store an entire `GridViewRow`  into a `HidenField` and i also want to retrieve that  row from the  `HidenField`.
How to do this?

Note: I don't want to avoid Javascript global variables.

Comment: `DataGridViewRow` is a winforms class, do you mean `GridViewRow`? Can i ask why you want to store all values in that HiddenField? Just enable `ViewState` if it's not already enabled.

Comment: sorry it's GridView i need to store selected row into hidden field so that i can perform some actions on that row of GriView at different events.And i also don't want to use ViewState.Because i have multiple instance of that user control on one page.